# how to access flutter bloc in the initState method?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

In the code shown below , the dispatch event is called from within the build method after getting the BuildContext object. What if I wish to do is to dispatch an event during processing at the start of the page within the initState method itself ?

If I use didChangeDependencies method , then I am getting this error : 
`BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type FileManagerBloc.` how to fix this?

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: BlocProvider<FileManagerBloc>(
          builder: (context)=>FileManagerBloc(),
          child: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.blueGrey, child: TopMenuBar()),
              Expanded(
                child: BlocBuilder<FileManagerBloc,FileManagerState>(
                  builder: (context , state){
                    return GridView.count(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      children: getFilesListWidget(context , state),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    logger.i('Did change dependency Called');
    final FileManagerBloc bloc = BlocProvider.of<FileManagerBloc>(context) ;
    Messenger.sendGetHomeDir()
        .then((path) async {
      final files = await Messenger.sendListDir(path);
        bloc.dispatch(SetCurrentWorkingDir(path)) ;
        bloc.dispatch(UpdateFileSystemCacheMapping(path , files)) ;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you are initializing the instance of `FileManagerBloc` inside the `BlocProvider` which is, of course inaccessible to the parent widget. I know that helps with automatic cleanup of the `Bloc` but if you want to access it inside `initState` or `didChangeDependencies` then you have to initialize it at the parent level like so,

```
FileManagerBloc _fileManagerBloc;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _fileManagerBloc= FileManagerBloc();
  _fileManagerBloc.dispatch(LoadEducation());
}

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: BlocProvider<FileManagerBloc>(
          builder: (context)=> _fileManagerBloc,
          child: SafeArea(
      child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(color: Colors.blueGrey, child: TopMenuBar()),
              Expanded(
                child: BlocBuilder<FileManagerBloc,FileManagerState>(
                  builder: (context , state){
                    return GridView.count(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      crossAxisCount: 3,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                      children: getFilesListWidget(context , state),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
      ),
    ),
        ));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _fileManagerBloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    logger.i('Did change dependency Called');
    Messenger.sendGetHomeDir()
        .then((path) async {
      final files = await Messenger.sendListDir(path);
        _fileManagerBloc.dispatch(SetCurrentWorkingDir(path)) ;
        _fileManagerBloc.dispatch(UpdateFileSystemCacheMapping(path , files)) ;
    });
  }
```

alternatively, if `FileManagerBloc` was provided/initialized at a grandparent `Widget` then it could easily be accessible at `this` level through `BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);`

Answer (score 2):

you can use it in `didChangeDependencies` method rather than `initState`.

**Example**

```dart
 @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    final CounterBloc counterBloc = BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context);
    //do whatever you want with the bloc here.
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Comment: BlocProvider.of<CounterBloc>(context is raising an error , I have updated my question , please suggest a fix

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. It's a legit way of accessing bloc. I am using it in `didChangeDependencies`. In parent widget I have `BlocProvider` so I have access to the bloc in child widgets.

I am using it to fire event using `counterBloc.add(...)` every time I navigate to specific view.

Comment: to fire bloc events in didChangeDependencies is very bad practice - check how many times this can fire in complex widgets especially. It is safe to use context here, but not consistent.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**
Step 1: need apply singleton pattern on Bloc class

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  static AuthBloc? _instance;
  static AuthBloc get instance {
    if (_instance == null) _instance = AuthBloc();
    return _instance!;
  }
  ....
  ....
```

Step 2: use AuthBloc.instance on main.dart for Provider

```
void main() async {
  runApp(MultiBlocProvider(
    providers: [
      BlocProvider(
        create: (context) => AuthBloc.instance,
      ),
      ...
      ...
    ],
    child: App(),
  ));
}
```

Now you can use Bloc without context

1. you can get state by AuthBloc.instance.state from initState or **anywhere**
2. you can add event from anywhere by AuthBloc.instance.add(..)
3. you also call BlocA from another BlocB very simple